# can you play youtube videos in your android application

Tags: android, youtube

I wanted to know if i can play youtube videos in my android application without any legal processes?

Comment: or you asking about the copyrights or the code how to do the same?

Comment: copyright issues is any

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about programming.

Comment: Hi David, Sure if you feel this question shouldn't be here. please close it. will keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the YouTube Android Player Api to do so,

the following links will tell you how to set up the app for playing you tube videos.

1.) https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/ 
   Check out the getting started section. You'll need an account in Google Developers Console and api keys.

2.) http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-youtube-client-on-android--cms-22858
  this link provides a sample and tutorial with code...

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **WebView** for this if you don't want to do the **getting the key from Google Developer Console** stuff.